# How do spring scopes work when application is used as an importable library/JAR

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a spring boot application **J**. J used to be a web application in itself, but now it is not and is being imported as a library by another spring boot app **X**, which is a web app. X uses methods of J to do certain things and passes certain arguments - user name and email for example.

In J, I was using request scope in J for stateful beans (which were storing user name and email). I would like to know that now when J is not a web application but a library, how scopes like session and request would work here for beans of J, as these scopes work specifically with http requests and sessions. Should I use prototype instead?

Let me know if more details/clarity are needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can continue to use scopes as before in the library J. When it is imported in web application X as a dependency, the code will run as part of the HTTP requests within the web app. This is how a lot of Spring libraries work.